# Why to store data in state in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to understand what we lose if we don't store the data in `state`. We can still trigger re-render by using `this.setState({})`. Please provide in-depth analysis.

Note that I am not concerned to maintain the state of application(usually done via Redux, Mobx etc.)

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    // this.state = { counter: 0 };//Am I loosing something by not doing in this way
  }
  counter = 0;
  increment() {
    this.counter++;
    this.setState({});//trigger re-render as new object is set to state
    // this.state.counter++;
    // this.setState(this.state);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>Click button to increment counter</h2>
        <button type="button" onClick={()=>this.increment()}>{this.counter}</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
//export default App;

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.body
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: If you are using `forceUpdate()` or `this.setState({})`, you're doing something wrong. For values for which a change should trigger a re-render, you should use local state or props or redux store.

Comment: @MithunShreevatsa We need to call this.setState anyway to reflect the changes whether you declare application data as a state property or directly as class property.

Comment: There seems to be misunderstanding around this.state/this.setState. I recommend reading their documentation: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#adding-local-state-to-a-class. Most importantly: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly

Comment: I like the question because it is one of the core design principals in react, and questioning it is a good way to learn it's benefits. check out my answer below.

Comment: If someone posted "you don't lose anything by not using state", it would certainly get downvoted, but it might be the unpopular truth.

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼwould you say that classes in JS are redundant since you already have objects? there are levels of abstractions that were made to make life easier. saying that they are necessary can sometimes be true, but you should be cautious not to dismiss valid solutions.

Answer (score 7):

One of the biggest things you'd lose are lifecycle methods and maintainability. The whole idea behind React's `state` is to make it easier to keep data in sync both in that component and in any child components being passed data from that state, but for all that to work as intended, you need to update the state using `this.setState()` and read from it through `this.state`.

What React does when calling `this.setState()` (besides updating the state) is go through the necessary lifecycle steps as well. One of the main things it does then is re-render the component (and it's children), but as you said, you can trigger that using `this.setState({})` which to some extent is true, but only if you're also okay with losing:

**Performance**

JavaScript is fast. React is fast. What do you get when you cross fast with fast? I don't know, but it's probably something really fast. Especially if you like using React's `PureComponent`, which is exactly the same as `Component` with the difference that [PureComponent](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent) implements [shouldComponentUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) using shallow state and props comparison, whereas `Component` doesn't. What this means is that if you don't update anything (state and props both stay the same), the `PureComponent` won't re-render the component, whereas `Component` will. If you don't use React's state system, you can't really use `PureComponent` for better performance, nor can you implement `shouldComponentUpdate`, since you can't compare your old data with your new data. You'd have to re-implement that performance feature yourself.

**Stability**

Saying goodbye to React's state system in favor of a hacky solution also means saying goodbye to application stability, and saying hello to more problems down the road than you can count. Let's take the performance problems from the above point, and let's put them to scale. In order for you to have a more performant application, you'd have to either repeat the above for the whole application, or create a generic solution that you could re-use across components. Not to mention the fact that remembering to call `this.setState({})` every time you update the data, just to make the component re-render. Forget it once, and your application will start to display inconsistent data, because even though "your state" updated, React's state hasn't. Scale that up, and you've got a problem.

**Colleagues that don't want to hurt you**

Let's face it. You're probably either new to programming, new to React, or haven't worked in a team, and that's okay, we all start from somewhere. What's really important, though, is not making your team want to hurt you so bad you'd **have to** pick a new specialty. One that doesn't require fingers and/or eyes.
The benefit of using tried and tested frameworks, as well as using them correctly, is that there's less hassle for everybody. Nobody has to create and maintain hacky solutions to already existing use cases. Nobody has to tear their hair out due to inconsistent rendering. Nobody has to lose an eye or break any fingers because **somebody** thought it'd be a good idea to reinvent the wheel, but this time as a cube.

**TL;DR & Final words**

1. Don't reinvent the wheel. It already exists, and it's round
2. Work smart, not hard
3. Either use React's **built-in** state system or Redux/MobX (see 1.)
4. Use `this.setState` for updating, `this.state` for reading. [Don't directly mutate state](https://daveceddia.com/why-not-modify-react-state-directly/), as React won't call any lifecycle methods, resulting in unexpected behavior and bugs

Comment: @DanielDubovski I won't argue with you on that. Yeah, they have nothing to do with each other, but what I meant by that was the following scenario: You have a HOC that holds some kind of state (eg. theme preferences) and sends it down to it's children, grandchildren, etc. Now, that component is (at least, regarding the theme preferences) your single source of truth. If you mess something up, or forget to add `this.setState({})` whenever you update the state, it's not only gonna affect just that HOC, but everything that uses it's state.

Comment: Yea I am new to react and want to understand the underlying concepts deeply. And often comparing the alternates gives deeper insight about subtle things.

Comment: Contrary to your statement, don't we need to call `this.setState` every time we update the state?

Comment: Yes, you do, that's not what I was saying. Yes, you have to call `this.setState`, but you should also store the data inside the `state` then as well. 
See: https://gist.github.com/xprnio/de01551e87feda5376a0c7a557f93f97

Answer (score 1):

Setting component state on a component instance can lead to *buggy component* and have an impact on maintability of the component.

**Correctness of Component state isn't guaranteed**

If you generate clicks faster than `this.counter` is incremented, the *computed `counter` isn't guaranteed to be correct*.

`setState` guarantees that multiple calls to it are batched together to be applied.
For this reason, `counter` value is guaranteed.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({counter: prevState.counter + 1}))
```

**No separation of rendering logic from state mutation**

Also, in use cases where you have to avoid a render when the component state didn't change, `React.Component` lifecycle methods like [`shouldComponentUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate) captures the next state _effectively separating the decision to render from update to state.

Keeping state on the component instance will have you computing the next state, comparing it to the previous one and deciding whether to force a rerender. 
This can become difficult to maintain if you have more state to manage for the component.

Comment: I doubt if we can generate faster clicks to break the expected output as clickHandler will anyway executed for each click no matter how fast you have clicked. Apart from all the benefits that state offers, my only concern is does it going to make any difference in that simple increment example

Comment: I was able to click fast in succession and reproduce an inconsistent counter. While a user may not interact with your application in this manner, there are applications where correctness is important. If you're up for experimentation, you can use selenium to drive a browser to view your application and perform clicks so fast to reproduce this.

Answer (score -1):

One specific thing I can think of is that `state` and `props` are big things in react.

For instance, when you call `.setState` it isn't exactly a *trigger to update ui* but rather a queued update request.

Why does it matter? 
Several reasons ([and more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#using-state-correctly)):

1. A `setState` doesn't necessarily mean that the component will indeed re-render. if the state is left the same as before, react will notice, and will skip the render cycle which gives you a performance boost (and is one of the key advantages on top of the virtual DOM).
2. `setState` is async (usually), and several setState can happen before a single render. thus, `setState({a:true});setState({a:false});` can in theory just skip the intermediate render (performance boost again).

One other thing is the idea that there is only one source of truth to a react component.

This is a design principal that allows easier development and debugging as it helps with code readability. React is just a *View* framework (as in MVC / MV*, just without the M). It is up to you to do the rest. Since it is just a View, Components are essentially just HTML (or rather, JSX) representation (or bindings, depending on lexicon) of plain data.
That data is *state*, and therefor has a special status.
It makes it much easier to think of (and code) React, with the understanding the Components are just `(state) => { <html>}` functions. when you want to see where the state changes, you just look for `setState`. as simple as that. you could of course store other things as class members, but that would defeat the purpose of simplicity and readability.

*PS: the above also means that time-travel is easy. you just play the state changes backwards (in theory) which is also a cool benefit of keeping things simple.

Comment: I understand the benefits that state offers. But in this OP of simple counter increment does it makes any difference?